# SQL to Exclude a Value from a Sequence

Tags: sql, db2

I have this code which I am using to find the next available Number in a Sequence. For example here is the data:

```
YEBX0001
YEBX0002
YEBX0003
YEBXTEMP - This is the Problem in the Source Data.
```

The Query below returns

```
NULL
YEBX003
YEBX002
YEBX001
```

How can I change my below query to exclude the YEBXTEMP value? as this is what is causing the Null as its not a numerical value within the sequence.

Code:

```
 select concat(left(mmitno,4),concat(repeat('0', 4-length(trim(RIGHT(TRIM
 (MMITNO),4)+0 ))),trim(RIGHT(TRIM(MMITNO),4)+0 ))) FROM MITMAS 
 WHERE MMITNO LIKE CONCAT(LEFT('YEBX0001',4),'%') and mmitty in (95,96) 
 ORDER BY MMITNO DESC
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Just where `MMITNO <> 'YEBXTEMP'` is too easy I suppose? :-)

Comment: DB2 is the DBMS

Comment: Uh, _why_ are you doing this?  What are you doing with these values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select concat(left(mmitno,4),concat(repeat('0', 4-length(trim(RIGHT(TRIM
 (MMITNO),4)+0 ))),trim(RIGHT(TRIM(MMITNO),4)+0 ))) FROM MITMAS 
 WHERE MMITNO LIKE CONCAT(LEFT('YEBX0001',4),'%') and mmitty in (95,96)
```

**and MMITNO <> 'YEBXTEMP'**

```
ORDER BY MMITNO DESC
```

Comment: Thank you. This has worked for my original requirement. How would I search for the MMITNO which has the highest Numerical sequence and then add on 1 to that? For example with my original Test Data how could I amend my code to look at YEBXTMP and see this is not in the number sequence and add a +1 to the number before this?

Comment: im not sure if i got your question correctly but you may try this sql:    select 'YEBX'||avc from
(select max(substr(MMITNO,5,4)) +1 as avc from MITMAS);